# ifdef command not found (GNU make 3.81)

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following `makefile` for a simple helloWorld program:

```
helloWorld: helloWorld.cpp
        echo "Argument entered is $(foo)"
        ifdef foo
        echo "Defined.";
        else
        echo "Not defined.";
        endif
        g++ -Wall -pedantic -g helloWorld.cpp -o h
```

When I invoke `make` from the command line like so: `make foo=bar`, I get the following error:

```
bar
"not set"
echo "Argument entered is bar"
Argument entered is bar
ifdef foo
make: ifdef: Command not found
make: *** [helloWorld] Error 127
```

I have gone through some of the links here on SO regarding this error but have not yet been able to solve this issue.

Comment: `ifdef` is a make construct you have it indented like a shell command. Don't do that. Remove the leading tab.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?    There is no C++ involved.

Comment: See [Example of a Conditional](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example) in the GNU make manual for how to do exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: @EtanReisner: That's an _answer_, not a comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You have the make directives (`ifdef`, `else` and `endif`) indented like shell commands.

See [Example of a Conditional](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Example) in the GNU make manual for how to do exactly this sort of thing.

```
libs_for_gcc = -lgnu
normal_libs =

foo: $(objects)
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(libs_for_gcc)
else
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(normal_libs)
endif
```